# Print Dygraph chart

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I'm trying to print a Div, containing a dygraph as follows:

javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function PrintElem(elem)
            {               
                Popup(document.getElementById(elem).innerHTML);
            }

            function Popup(data) 
            {
                var mywindow = window.open('', 'my div', 'height=400,width=800');
                mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>my div</title>');                
                mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
                console.log(data);
                mywindow.document.write(data);
                mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

                mywindow.print();
                mywindow.close();

                return true;
            }    
        </script>
```

In HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="Print Div" onclick="PrintElem('divName')" />
```

**Problem statement:**

The dygraph ("divName"), contains a script which plots the actual chart in HTML.
The print function can not cater for this when trying to print the innerHTML.

Is there another way to do this?
Thanks!

Comment: Dygraph use acanvas for drawing, so you probably need to convert the canvas to an image and then print the image. Here it shows how to export a Dygraph object as png: http://cavorite.com/labs/js/dygraphs-export/