# Programmatically Printing Dygraphs to a printer via Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, printing, dygraphs

---

I'm currently working on an Asp.net website with C# code behinds that is trying to programmatically print a Dygraphs chart on a printer via javascript.  When I tried to print the DIV containing the Dygraphs I was only able to print the chart's x and y axis; no chart appeared on paper.

Later, I found an article on StackOverflow ([Print Dygraph chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14400599/print-dygraph-chart)) where someone was trying to do the same thing and the suggestion they received was to  try to use Dygraphs built in Dygraph.export.asPNG function, contained in the dygraphs-extra.js file, to convert the Dygraph into a PNG image before printing it out on a printer.  I tried this too, and all I was able to print out was a small square icon representing the Dygraph.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Here's my code:

```
var graph = null;
var row1 = null;
var options = {
            labels: row1,
            labelsDivStyles: {
                        'text-align': 'center',
                        'background': 'white',
                        'font-size': '12px',
                        'color': 'black
                    },  //labelsDivStyles
            'colors': ['red', 'orange', 'green', 'blue'],
            labelsSeperateLines: true,
            labelsDiv: "labels",
            legend: 'always',
            title: 'Temperature vs. Time',
            titleHeight: 18,
            ylabel: 'Temperature (c)',
            xlabel: 'Time',
            axes: {
                x:{
                    axisLabelFontSize: 12,
                    axisLabelColor: 'black',
                    axisLineColor: 'black',
                    gridLineWidth: 2,
                    drawGrid: true,
                    drawAxis: true
                },//x
                y:{
                    axisLabelFontSize: 12,
                    axisLabelColor: 'black',
                    axisLineColor: 'black',
                    gridLineWidth: 2,
                    drawGrid: true,
                    drawAxis: true,
                    independentTicks: true
                }//y
            }//axes


        };

var drawGraph = function(data){
    var arry = toArray(data);
    var firstRow = arr[0];
    row1 = firstRow;
    var data = arry.slice(1); //Remove first element (labels);
    var img = document.getElementById(“DygraphDiv”);
    return new Dygraph(img, data, options);

}


function graphTemps(){

    var stringData = FetchDataFromDatabase();
    graph = drawGraph(stringData);
}

function printGraph(){
    //Create the image 
    var img = document.getElementById(“DygraphDiv”);
    Dygraph.export.asPNG(graph, img, options); 

    //Print the Dygraph image on a printer
    var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=300,width=600');
    printWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Graph DIV Contents</title>');
    printWindow.document.write('<head><body>');
    printWindow.document.write("<img src=" + img + ">");
    printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
    printWindow.doucment.close();

}
```