# How do I print a dygraph graph?

Tags: printing, dygraphs

I need to print a page that has 4 dygraphs on it. I found a previous post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14400599/print-dygraph-chart) about it, but it refers to [this document](https://cavorite.com/labs/js/dygraphs-export/) which is 10 years old and for the life of me, I cannot get it to work.

For one thing, the example shown shows the following:

```js
var g = new Dygraph(...)
var img = document.getElementById('demoimg')
Dygraph.Export.asPNG(dygraph, img)
```

That last line should be this, shouldn't it?

Dygraph.Export.asPNG(g, img);

Regardless, I get this error:

Uncaught TypeError: Dygraph.createCanvas is not a function

Is dygraphs.extras.js current? Is there some other way to generate images and print graphs?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to convert the graphs in the first place? I would expect them to print just fine.

Comment: They do not print correctly. The are a canvas which does not print as they are dynamic. I was able to find a html to pdf converter which works and I printed from that.

Comment: That document was written *long* ago, so it’s for a __very__ old version of Dygraphs. The API has changed in the meantime. It can probably be adapted, given that the hard part (getting things to print/export) is already done.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to convert to PDF file first, then print and that worked. jspdf fits the bill. [https://www.npmjs.com/package/jspdf[][1]](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jspdf%5B%5D%5B1%5D)